# Split copy value from another textbox

Tags: jquery

How to split the value copied from dropdown? I need only the ACR-01 split('.').

Here my code and sample of fiddle.

```
<label>Category</label>
<select name="maincode" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onchange = "GetChangedValue(this);">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="ACR-01.A">SUPPLIES</option>
    <option value="ACR-02.B">IT EQUIPMENT</option>
    <option value="ACR-03.C">OFFICE EQUIPMENT</option>
</select>
</br>
<input type="text" name="maincopy" id="maincopy" value="">

<script>
$('[name="maincode"]').change(function() {
   $('[name="maincopy"]').val($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xqGLS/6/

Answer (score 0):

Basically `.split()` will return an array of strings, you can access the fist element of an array by using `[0]`

Try,

```
$('[name="maincode"]').change(function() {
   $('[name="maincopy"]').val($(this).val().trim().split('.')[0]);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/xqGLS/7/)

Comment: what the use of trim?

Comment: @user3318208 It will remove the leading and the trailing white spaces in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   $('[name="maincopy"]').val($(this).val().split(".")[0]);
```